# Convert Crystal Report to PDF/A-3 format using c#

Tags: c#, itext7, pdfa, pdfa3

I know to convert from crystal report to pdf, but i cannot find any document to convert from crystal report to pdf/a-3 format.

Is it possible using IItext7 or any other libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You can automate the process of exporting a Crystal Report to PDF, and converting the resulting PDF to PDF/A.

One of the 3rd-party Crystal Reports automation tools listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched) already provides that feature.